# Struct inheritance in Julia

Tags: julia

Given I have some struct:

```
julia> struct Car
           wheels::Int64
           engine::Int64
           model::String
       end
```

Is there a way I can make a new struct and inherit the the attributes of the `Car` I defined above (similar to class inheritance in Object Orientated Programming)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/composition-and-inheritance-the-julian-way/11231) discussion and [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/composition-and-inheritance-the-julian-way/11231/3?u=cojua8) answer.

The best way to achieve such behaviour is to access struct members from functions rather than directly accessing fields, and just use composition for your struct.

Then you can use a [forwarding macro](https://juliahub.com/ui/Packages/ReusePatterns/iFGTB/0.2.0). e.g:

```
using ReusePatterns

struct Car
    wheels::Int64
    engine::Int64
    model::String
end

wheels(c::Car) = c.wheels
engine(c::Car) = c.engine
model(c::Car) = c.model

struct DoorCar
    car::Car
    doors::Int64
end

@forward (DoorCar, :car) Car
```